# Does ASP.NET Core support SQL Server CE now?

Tags: asp.net-core, sql-server-ce, asp.net-core-1.0

If supported, which package should I install in order to use SQL Server CE?
Thanks.

> Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact 4.0.8876.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0).
>
> Package EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 1.0.0.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0).

Comment: you may use https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact with ASP.NET Core 1.0, but only using the full .NET runtime. It does not work under the .NET Core runtime.

Comment: @Set your comment should be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

EF Core will handle it.

Use the SQLite / SQL Server Compact Toolbox extension for Visual Studio 2017 by ErikEJ.

"EF Core, released simultaneously with .NET Core, is a lightweight and extensible version of Entity Framework that works on both .NET Core and .NET Framework. It has support for Microsoft SQL Server, SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition, and IBM DB2 with more to come, such as Oracle." (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access)